# ffmpeg trim mp3 - determine precisely the start and end times of section to be trimmed

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I have a long mp3 track of an audio book (more than 9 hours long) that I would like to trim using ffmpeg.

The sample code below is used to trim an mp3 section by providing the start and end times. However, when I determine the start and end times, then checking the output file, it's not as precisely as I want, sometimes several minutes ahead/before the desired point.

```
import subprocess
file = r'audio book.mp3'
track_name = "trimmed section"
output = r'D:\{0}'.format(track_name)
start = '01:26:04'
end = '01:33:17'

d = subprocess.getoutput('ffmpeg -i "{0}" -ss {1} -to {2} -c copy {3}.mp3"'
                     .format(file, start, end, output))

print(d)
```

Is there a way to determine with accuracy the real start and end time of an mp3 audio track, to be given afterwards as inputs to the code...to trim the desired sections all at once, without the need to adjust/fine-tune the start and end time manually??

Comment: Yes, there is, check `atrim` audio filter. You can't use `-c copy` with that though.

Comment: Have you looked at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking ? but it seems like your doing the slow seek versions so it should be fine. So the start time is wrong but the duration seems ok?

Comment: @oguzismail would you please give a code example??

Comment: @MattiasWadman In fact my issue is not the code itself, I want to find a way to precisely set the timestamp of start and end of a section to be trimmed...for example I have a 9 hour audiobook that I am trying to split it into chapters. When I play the track using Winamp for example, to know the start and end of chapter 1, then when I trim it using ffmpeg, it's not exactly trimmed, in fact it's chapter 1 + few minutes of chapter 2...